# getting an attribute value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the 31003 value from the attribute with jquery.

```
 <a class= "findOption" data-clickaction="changeFilter" data-actionvalue=" {"Company":"31003", "val": "mostrecent";}" href="javascript:void(0);">Most Recent</a>
```

I have tried,

$(".findOptions").attr('Company').value();

$(".findOptions").attr('data-actionvalue');

I am stuck.

Comment: `Company` is part of the string that is the value of `data-actionvalue`. `Company` is itself not an attribute. So you would need to do some searching in that string. It is also invalid HTML because you have double double quotes.

Comment: Avoid using double quotes here and there.... Distinguish them using single quotes and double quotes properly..

Comment: I think you will need to use single quotes as the data-actiionvalue attribute will read as `data-actionvalue=" {"` and `Company":"` will try act like another attribute. `"` < used to block in / open close the attribute data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [data method](http://api.jquery.com/data):

```
$('.findOption').data('actionvalue')['Company'];//findOption instead as noticed by @Vimalan
```

And as @Barmar indicated that html is invalid you should be doing like this in your html:

```
data-actionvalue='{"Company":"31003", "val": "mostrecent"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your HTML isn't correct. Since you're using double quotes in the JSON that's in `data-actionvalue`, you have to use single quotes as the delimiter around the attribute value. Otherwise, the quote before `Company` will end the attribute.

Also, you shouldn't have a semicolon (`;`)` in the value, that's not valid JSON.

```
<a class= "findOption" data-clickaction="changeFilter" data-actionvalue='{"Company":"31003", "val": "mostrecent"}' href="javascript:void(0);">Most Recent</a>
```

Then to get a particular property of the data, you need to access it with `.`:

```
$('.findOption').data('actionvalue').Company
```

or `[]`:

```
$('.findOption').data('actionvalue')['Company']
```

Comment: Great answer but i'm just curious. **If** this anchor tag is dynamically created won't it use double quotes by default?

Comment: @NewToJS It doesn't matter.

Comment: @NewToJS If it's created dynamically, then it doesn't use quotes at all, that's just part of the HTML syntax. If you create it dynamically you're just manipulating the DOM as objects.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal I'm asking our of curiosity.

Comment: @NewToJS If you use without quote then also it works.

Comment: @Barmar Okay thank you. I thought using something like `setAttribute('data-actionvalue','{"Company":"31003", "val": "mostrecent"}');` would output `data-actionvalue=` with double quotes. I know this question doesn't mention dynamic data. I'm just asking out of my own curiosity. "Sorry, I didn't mention dynamically created via javascript"

Comment: You need to understand that all the markup (quotes, angle brackets, entities) is just used for input and output, it's not part of the DOM itself. When you call functions like `setAttribute`, you're accessing the internal data, so quoting is not a concept that exists. You'll see the quotes if you call `.innerHTML`, and then it's up to the browser to generate proper markup.

Comment: @Barmar ah, I will be sure to remember this for future. Thank you very much, sorry I dragged the question away from the original question. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of corrections in your code:

1) Fix, 'actionvalue' as shown in my code.
2) Use findOption instead of findOptions (it does not exists in your code)

```js
var obj = $(".findOption").data('actionvalue');
$('#result').text(obj.Company);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class= "findOption" data-clickaction="changeFilter" data-actionvalue='{"Company":"31003", "val": "mostrecent"}' href="javascript:void(0);">Most Recent</a>

<br/>
<label id='result'/>
```

Comment: Woah, that `eval()` is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @Ja͢ck, $('.findOption').data('actionvalue')['Company'] or $('.findOption').data('actionvalue').Company is not working. So, I opted to use eval to get the result.

Comment: Doesn't work because it's not recognised as JSON because you're using single quotes for the keys and values ... instead, you should use double quotes inside and use single quotes for the HTML attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
$(".findOption").data('actionvalue')['Company'];
```